# How to filter products by size in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am filtering products by size, i selected all the li's user has selected 
using this jquery function :

```
var arr_size = [];
i = 0;
$(".filtersize li a").each(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected-filter")) {
        arr_size[i++]= $(this).text();
    }
});
```

this is working fine, but i am passing this array from ajax to codeigniter controller and i am saving size data as comma separated value in database :

size column:

> 'S','M','L','XL'

and javascript array also contains comma seperated value for eg. if user has selected two values it will contain S,M i am not able to search array values in db using like function is there any other function or method to achieve this my code is as follows:

```
var data = {id:pid,arr_s:arr_size};
var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>controlle/viewproducts";
var result = post_ajax(url, data);
```

> controller:

```
public function viewproducts()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $size_arr=$this->input->post('arr_s');
    $result['product'] = $this->product_m->get_product_size_filter($id,$size_arr);
    $this->load->view('product_filter_view/view_product',$result);
}
```

> Model:

```
public function get_product_size_filter($id,$size) {
    $where_query = '';
    $size_array = explode(',', $size);
    foreach ($size_array as $size_item) {
        $size = "$size_item";
        $where_query .= "dg_products.size LIKE '%$size%' OR ";
    }

    $where_query = rtrim($where_query, " OR ");

    $this->db->select('dg_products.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating');
    $this->db->from('dg_products');
    $this->db->join('dg_rating', 'dg_products.id = dg_rating.product_id','left');
    $this->db->where('dg_products.category_id',$id);
    $this->db->where($where_query);
    $this->db->group_by("dg_products.id");
    $query = $this->db->get();   
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of like can you split this string on comma delimiter and use OR inside WHERE clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can convert your **size** string to array and run query.
Below example code:

```
public function viewproducts() 
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id', true);
    $size_string = $this->input->post('arr_s', true);
    $size_array = explode(',', $size_string);
    $result['product'] = array();

    foreach ($size_array as $size_item) {
        $size = "'$size_item'";
        $result['product'][] = $this->product_m->get_product_size_filter($id, $size);
    }

    $this->load->view('product_filter_view/view_product', $result);
}
```

If you don't want run multi db queries, you can use:

```
public function viewproducts() 
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id', true);
    $sizes = $this->input->post('arr_s', true);
    $result['product'] = $this->product_m->get_product_size_filter($id, $sizes);

    $this->load->view('product_filter_view/view_product', $result);
}
```

Here is model:

```
public function get_product_size_filter($id, $size)
{
    $where_query = '';
    $size_array = explode(',', $size);

    foreach ($size_array as $size_item) {
        $size = "'$size_item'";
        $where_query .= "size LIKE '%$size%' OR ";
    }

    $where_query = rtrim($where_query, " OR ");

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('dg_products');
    $this->db->where($where_query);
    $query = $this->db->get();   
    return $query->result();
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
public function get_product_size_filter($id,$size)
{
    $where_query = '';
    $size_array = explode(',', $size);

    foreach ($size_array as $size_item) {
        $size = "$size_item";
        $where_query .= "dg_products.size LIKE '%$size%' OR ";
    }

    $where_query = rtrim($where_query, " OR ");

    $this->db->select('dg_products.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating');
    $this->db->from('dg_products');
    $this->db->join('dg_rating', 'dg_products.id = dg_rating.product_id','left');
    $this->db->where('dg_products.category_id',$id);
    $this->db->where("($where_query)");
    $this->db->group_by("dg_products.id");
    $query = $this->db->get();   
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i am getting all the products in view i have updated my model.

Comment: SELECT `dg_products`.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating FROM `dg_products` LEFT JOIN `dg_rating` ON `dg_products`.`id` = `dg_rating`.`product_id` WHERE `dg_products`.`category_id` = '4' AND `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%S%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%M%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%L%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%XL%' GROUP BY `dg_products`.`id`  this is the query which is generated

Comment: You have where cond before LIKE. Thats why you get all products

Comment: There is an error in sql query : Unknown column 'S' in 'where clause'

SELECT `dg_products`.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating FROM `dg_products` LEFT JOIN `dg_rating` ON `dg_products`.`id` = `dg_rating`.`product_id` WHERE `dg_products`.`category_id` = '4' AND ('.dg_products.size LIKE '%S%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%M%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%L%' OR `dg_products`.`size` LIKE '%XL%'.') GROUP BY `dg_products`.`id`

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot replace ". Now must work, I updated the code again.

Comment: Glad to help :)